# .NET System.MissingMethodException

Tags: .net

I am trying to write a very simple program to evaluate a 3rd party library. I have added all the necessary .dll references to my project and have written the following code (boiler plate removed) which attempts to use the Controller class in the 3rd party library:

```
Controller controller = new Controller("192.168.42.190", Controller.CPU.S7300, "0.2");

controller.Connect();

Tag myTag = new Tag();

controller.ReadTag(myTag);

controller.Disconnect();
```

This code builds just fine and IntelliSense agrees that all is well. When I run this code however the line `controller.ReadTag(myTag);` causes a System.MissingMethodException.

I'm quite new to .NET and am confused as to why I am able to build the code above, use IntelliSense to view all the methods and properties on the Controller class (including ReadTag) only to have the code fail at runtime.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the 3rd party library code that throws the exception *inside* the `ReadTag` method?

Comment: Commonly this is caused by different version of dll being deployed to bin directory (one that doesn't have the method against you're compiling your evaluation program).

Comment: It is a DLL Hell problem, the assembly you run with is not the same as the assembly you referenced in your program.  Writing these kind of quick eval programs is indeed a very good idea.  This is a major fail whale, throw it away.  Lots of OPC libraries out there.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar *being deployed to bin directory*: or GAC

Comment: @DominicKexel I am not sure. How would I identify this? I have enabled the the 'Copy Local' flag so the DLL is being moved into the bin directory.

Comment: The problem is related to obfuscation. We are working with the publisher of the obfuscator to resolve this issue. Regards
CimQuest INGEAR

Answer (score 0):

Check the namespace. You may use the Controller as:

```
Namespace.Controller controller = ...
```

> This might be interfering with the same name of the default Controller.

Comment: @LukeEllis, it could be some DLL reference issues. Check if you have proper references added to your project / solution.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.missingmethodexception.aspx) states

> The exception that is thrown when there is an attempt to dynamically access a method that does not exist.

I would put my money on the `ReadTag` method not being there or renamed.

Comment: OK but why does IntelliSense think it is?

Comment: @LukeEllis beats me, could be from a cached version from an old DLL or even just plain wrong. It's best to stick to the *real* documentation for an API rather than relying on IntelliSense - if it's failing with a MME I'd be inclined to believe the IntelliSense is wrong or out of date...